# Is there a way in Golang to define a generic function type with varargs that can take any function as input?

Tags: go, generics

I am trying write a module that provides bookkeeping for task being executed. For that I need a way to take any function and a take list of variables as input and call the passed function with the list of arguments passed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Run[T any](f func(T), args T) {
    f(args)
}

func RunVarArgs[T any](f func(...T), args ...T) {
    f(args...)
}

type someStruct struct {
    str  string
    time int
}

func fn1(s someStruct) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(s.time) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(s.str + " ")
}

func fn2(str1 string, str2 string) {
    fmt.Println(str1 + str2)
}

func main() {
    data := someStruct{
        str:  "Hello World",
        time: 5,
    }

    // Below line will compile:
    Run(fn1, data)

    //Below line will not compile with errors:
    //1. Cannot 'use fn1' (type func(s someStruct)) as type func(...T)
    //2. Cannot use 'data' (type someStruct) as type T
    RunVarArgs(fn1, data)

    // Below line will not compile with error:
    //Cannot 'use fn2' (type func(str1 string, str2 string)) as type func(...string)
    RunVarArgs(fn2, "Hello", " World")
}
```

Is there any way around this ?

Comment: Not possible with pure generics.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. This works, but the only disadvantage of this approach is that you need to define the number of different args types expected, otherwise, the solution becomes complex and hard to manage.

```
type sampleStruct struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    // Type 1
    RunArg(Function1A, "arg1A")
    RunArg(Function1B, sampleStruct{name: "Jack"})
    // Type 2
    RunVarArgs(Function2A, "arg2A1", "arg2A2")
    RunVarArgs(Function2B, "arg2B1", "arg2B2")

}

type ArgRunner func(arg any)

type VarArgsRunner func(arg ...string)

func Function1A(arg1 any) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
}
func Function1B(arg1 any) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
}

func Function2A(arg1 ...string) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
}
func Function2B(arg1 ...string) {
    fmt.Println(arg1)
}

func RunArg(fun ArgRunner, args any) {
    fun(args)
}

func RunVarArgs(fun VarArgsRunner, args ...string) {
    fun(args[0], args[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call *absolutely* any function with any list of args - then you probably have little choice but to use `reflect`, e.g...

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type someStruct struct {
    str  string
    time int
}

func fn1(s someStruct) {
    fmt.Println("fn1", s.str)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(s.time) * time.Second)
}

func fn2(strs ...any) {
    fmt.Println("fn2")
    fmt.Println(strs...)
}

func main() {
    data := someStruct{
        str:  "Hello World",
        time: 1,
    }

    _ = Run(fn1, data)
    _ = Run(fn2, "Hello", " World")

    if err := Run(fn1, data, "too many"); err != nil {
        println("ERROR:", err.Error())
    }
    if err := Run(fn1); err != nil {
        println("ERROR:", err.Error())
    }
    if err := Run(fn2); err != nil {
        println("ERROR:", err.Error())
    }
}

func Run(fn any, args ...any) error {
    vfn := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    if vfn.Type().Kind() != reflect.Func {
        return errors.New("not a function")
    }
    l := len(args)
    nIn := vfn.Type().NumIn()
    if l < nIn && (!vfn.Type().IsVariadic() || l != nIn-1) {
        return errors.New("too few args")
    } else if l > nIn && !vfn.Type().IsVariadic() {
        return errors.New("too many args")
    }
    in := make([]reflect.Value, 0, l)
    for _, arg := range args {
        in = append(in, reflect.ValueOf(arg))
    }
    vfn.Call(in)
    return nil
}
```

[try on go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/u1369RIgqCP)

Answer (score -1):

if your question is about booking any function call, my suggestion(not very clean and nice but solves the main problem) is to do it like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Run1Args[A any](f func(A), arg1 A) {
    f(arg1)
}

func Run2Args[A, B any](f func(A, B), arg1 A, arg2 B) {
    f(arg1, arg2)
}

func Run3Args[A, B, C any](f func(A, B, C any), arg1 A, arg2 B, arg3 C) {
    f(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

// Add more RunNArgs depending on your code base

type someStruct struct {
    str  string
    time int
}

func fn1(s someStruct) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(s.time) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(s.str + " ")
}

func fn2(str1, str2 string) {
    fmt.Println(str1 + str2)
}

func main() {
    data := someStruct{
        str:  "Hello World",
        time: 5,
    }
    Run1Args(fn1, data)

    Run2Args(fn2, "Hello", " World")
}
```